# urllib3.Pool Manager has no attribute name

Tags: python, amazon-s3

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', target_url)
s3.put_object(ACL='public-read', Body= r.data, Bucket = bucket, Key = key, )
return r.data
```

Keeps giving me an error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PoolManager'"
Even though I already imported this from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager

Comment: Just prepend the line `import urllib3` and it will work. In your example, you import the entire module `urllib3`. If you want to import just the `PoolManager`, use `from urllib3 import PoolManager`, but then you don't need to use the prefix `urllib3.PoolManager()`, but just `PoolManager()`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, the problem was the name of my file, which was crawlib.py, renaming the file solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from urrlib3 import PoolManager
http = PoolManager()
```